# Installing additional packages through Rprofile

Tags: r, rprofile

I want to install additional packages besides the default ones every time I restart my R Session.

I have tried this: options(HTTPUserAgent = sprintf("R/%s R (%s)", getRversion(), paste(getRversion(), R.version$platform, R.version$arch, R.version$os)))
install.packages(c(
'shinydashboard',
'shinyWidgets',
'rlist',
'sortable',
'tidyverse',
'XML',
'DescTools',
'plotly',
'leaflet',
'tidyquant',
'umap'
))

And this options(defaultPackages = c(getOption("defaultPackages"), "tidyquant", ...)) neither of which works. If all I want to do is to install the tidyquant package upon the R Session restart, how do I get it to work inside the Rprofile file?

Comment: Why do you need to reinstall the packages upon every restart (as opposed to using library?

Comment: tidyquant is one of those packages that MUST be resintalled everytime. I am working through a corporate environment, the assumption being that the environment gets reset nightly

Comment: ah okay thanks. I was just checking that there was no misunderstanding over installation requirements vs library calls

Comment: That seems wrong. You can most likely do `mkdir -p ~/R/lib` and then install into your very own `~/R/lib` the packages you want, and also tell `Rprofile` to add it which is as simple as `.libPaths("~/R/lib")`

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely take @dirk-eddelbuettel's advice on this ([XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)), but it is possible if you add this to your .Rprofile:

```
.First <- function(){
 utils::install.packages("tidyquant", repos="https://cran.csiro.au/")
 library(tidyquant)
}
```

(This command is run before any packages are loaded so you need to specify the install.packages function comes from utils).

Not sure if this applies to windows; my system info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Monterey 12.4

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8/C/en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  stats     methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] tidyquant_1.0.4            quantmod_0.4.20           
[3] TTR_0.24.3                 PerformanceAnalytics_2.0.4
[5] xts_0.12.1                 zoo_1.8-10                
[7] lubridate_1.8.0           

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] magrittr_2.0.3   tidyselect_1.1.2 munsell_0.5.0   
 [4] colorspace_2.0-3 lattice_0.20-45  R6_2.5.1        
 [7] rlang_1.0.2      quadprog_1.5-8   fansi_1.0.3     
[10] dplyr_1.0.9      httr_1.4.3       tcltk_4.1.3     
[13] tools_4.1.3      grid_4.1.3       gtable_0.3.0    
[16] utf8_1.2.2       DBI_1.1.2        cli_3.3.0       
[19] ellipsis_0.3.2   assertthat_0.2.1 tibble_3.1.7    
[22] lifecycle_1.0.1  crayon_1.5.1     purrr_0.3.4     
[25] ggplot2_3.3.6    vctrs_0.4.1      curl_4.3.2      
[28] Quandl_2.11.0    glue_1.6.2       compiler_4.1.3  
[31] pillar_1.7.0     generics_0.1.2   scales_1.2.0    
[34] jsonlite_1.8.0   pkgconfig_2.0.3 
>
```

N.B. Choose your CRAN mirror accordingly (unless you also happen to be in Australia): https://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html

Comment: If i add that code to the .First param in my Rprofile library, I just want to make sure that it doesn't override any of the default loads that the company has already included in R Studio Pro

Comment: Seems unlikely (based on https://rviews.rstudio.com/2017/04/19/r-for-enterprise-understanding-r-s-startup/) but the easiest way to investigate would be to try it and see.